# AWS CloudFormation Transform LanguageExtensions policy error

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cloudformation-macro

I can't get this code [from the doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/function-refs-in-policy-attributes.html) to deploy:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09
Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions
Resources:
  Table:
    Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
```

Using `Transform: AWS::LanguageExtensions` always results in:

> User: arn:aws:iam::XXX:user/admin is not authorized to perform: cloudformation:CreateChangeSet on resource: arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:aws:transform/LanguageExtensions because no resource-based policy allows the cloudformation:CreateChangeSet action

Note that the user has full access rights.

Comment: Are you sure that your user tries to deploy the template? Maybe you are using some other user, IAM role or something like that?

Comment: Yes I'm sure it's the admin user, its arn is in the error message

Comment: I can't find any docs for the "AWS::LanguageExtensions" transform https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/transform-reference.html. Where did you find that?

Comment: Lol the page as been removed without notice in the release history. It's still indexed in the search tool https://docs.aws.amazon.com/search/doc-search.html?searchPath=documentation&searchQuery=LanguageExtensions but it redirects to the welcome page

Comment: Well it just came back, my link to the doc works again. But there is no github file for this page, it's weird

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has been removed from the documentation.